# cakepphp 2.3: Authentication via custom BaseAuthenticate

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I wrote a class AlephBaseAuthenticate that extents BaseAuthenticate which works fine:

```
<?php

 // Authentication against Aleph X-Service
 // user and password for x-service see aleph.ini

 App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
 App::uses('IniReader', 'Configure');
 Configure::config('default', new IniReader());

 class AlephAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {
    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        // Do things for Aleph here.
        // Return an array of user + group-id if they could authenticate the user,
        // return false if not
        // verification = empty works, so we have to check lenght of verification!
        $configfile = Configure::read('configfile');
        Configure::load($configfile, 'default');
        $alephxurl = Configure::read('aleph.xurl');
        $xlib = Configure::read('aleph.xlib');

        $username = $request->data['Users']['username'];
        $password = $request->data['Users']['password'];

        $req = $alephxurl . 'library=' . $xlib . '&verification=' . $password . '&op=bor_info&bor_id=' . $username;
        $userxml = file_get_contents($req);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($userxml);
        $error = $xml->error;
        if($error == 'Error retrieving Patron System Key' || strlen($password) == 0){
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $data['username'] = $xml->z303->{'z303-name'};
            $data['group'] = $xml->z303->{'z303-profile-id'};
            $data['id'] = $xml->z303->{'z303-id'};
            return $data;
        }        
    }
}
```

In my UserController I added

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
           'authenticate' => array(
              'Aleph'
            )
       )
);

function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'login', 'logout');
}
```

The problem is: Only in UsersController.php, action "login", I can access this->Auth->user('id'), and, $this->Auth->allow('index', 'login', 'logout') doesn't work at all. Access to every action after login throughs a "You are not authorized to access that location". Looks like authentication doesn't work at all.

Any idea whats wrong here?

Thanks,

Christoph

Comment: I get the error message
"Notice (8): session_start(): Unexpected end of serialized data [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 661]" when I return $data.

Christoph

Comment: I solved it. The values from $xml have to be casted via (string):
    (string)$xml->z303->{'z303-name'};